# how to trigger a quickbuild flow after github push

Tags: quickbuild

I want quickbuild to automatically run on each push detected on a github repository. How can I do that?

I already have a flow that clones and executes `mvn deploy` but I am missing an automatic trigger.

Answer (score 0):

QuickBuild 5.1 adds the ability of detecting pull requests and trigger relevant builds off them. Refer to the GitHub integration guide for details:
http://wiki.pmease.com/display/QB51/Working+with+GitHub

Comment: please provide some more details for solution :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is somewhat useless. Why not support the github webhook `POST` syntax instead. Would allow for more flexible build setups.